# Facing issues to create bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, storage

I am trying to create the bucket in google cloud platform. But due to some issues I am not able to create the bucket. Is there any other way to create the bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not able to create the bucket through console, you can create it from cloud shell also.

The command for creating bucket is mentioned below:

`gsutil mb gs://BUCKET_NAME`

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways of creating a bucket in Google Cloud Platform

1. Via GCP Console:
   The below link will walk you through the steps to create a bucket
   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets
2. Through gsutil command:
   This command will help you in creating a bucket:

   gsutil mb [-b (on|off)] [-c <_class>] [-l <_location>] [-p <proj_id>]
   [--retention ] gs://<bucket_name>...
   Refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mb) link to learn more about gsutil command
3. Using API:
   [This](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-create) link will walk you through various things that you need to follow to
   create a bucket using API

But before this you will need permission to create a bucket. Do check if you have the required permissions.

Permissions that allows you to create a bucket:

storage.buckets.create - allows you to create new bucket

storage.objects.create - allows you to create new object

For more information on IAM permissions check [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) link